# Running a docker-based lambda with SAM and docker-compose

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, docker-compose, aws-sam

Trying to build a docker based lambda using SAM and test it locally within a docker-compose, as the lambda needs to server other components built by the compose.
Thing is, SAM itself runs in a container which means that I'm not clear on how to build that container within the docker-compose file and have it run the `sam build` and `sam local start-api`

Any general guidelines on how to build the `docker-compose.yml` file and any other must have resources would be helpful!

Comment: At the moment, the only ways to do this seem rather hacky: https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/55